# Adding features to a vectorlayer using checkbox

Tags: vector, openlayers, feature-layer

I'm trying to add features to a vector layer using a checkbox.
    var featureOverlay = new.ol.FeatureOverlay;

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.is(":checked")){
        featureOverlay.addFeature(feature);
    }else{
        featureOverlay.removeFeature(feature);
    }
});

var polyCoords = [];
var coords = "95.61,38.60 95.22,37.98 95.60,37.66 94.97,37.65".split(' ');

for (var i in coords) {
  var c = coords[i].split(',');
  polyCoords.push(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(c[0]), parseFloat(c[1])], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
}

var feature = new ol.Feature({
geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([polyCoords])
})

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [feature]
    })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
    }),
    layer            
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([95.22, 37.98], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to add the FeatureOverlay to the map and then use the onchange event of checkbox.

```
var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
    map: map
});
var updateFeat = function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.is(":checked")){
        featureOverlay.addFeature(feature);
    }else{
        featureOverlay.removeFeature(feature);
    }
};
// each: initialize the status of the feature when the page opens
// change: Update the status of the feature on each click on the checkbox
$("input:checkbox").each(updateFeat).change(updateFeat);
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oterral/suh1qqxe/2/)

Comment: Yep, I found that out myself over the weekend.  You beat me to the answer.  @oterral:  What if you have multiple arrays that you want to turn on and off individually by their own checkbox?  ".each" function?